# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop in table React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, unique-key

I don't know where is the error I'm getting in the console, everything seems fine, does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

[Unique key error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B6Q6.png)

```
<TableBody>
   {announcements.map((announcement) => (
       <TableRow
          key={announcement.id}
          sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
        >
        <TableCell align="left">
            <Box display='flex' alignItems='center'>
                <Avatar src={announcement.photoUrl} alt={announcement.announcementTitle}
                   style={{ height: 50, width: 50, marginRight: 20 }} />
                   <span>{announcement.announcementTitle}</span>
             </Box>
         </TableCell>
         <TableCell align="right">
             <Button onClick={() => handleSelectAnnouncement(announcement)} startIcon={<Edit />} />
              <Button startIcon={<Delete />} color='error' />
          </TableCell>
         </TableRow>
   ))}
</TableBody>
```

After changing to key={index} I get this error, but I still don't know what is wrong. There are only 6 ID fields in the database, and it can't be duplicated anywhere.

[warning after update key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqQhW.png)

Below is a link to the repository because there is quite a lot of code.

[Last commit on GitHub](https://github.com/Thominik/study.me/tree/prod/studymev1.1)

Comment: It is a `"Warning"` and it is from `<TableRow>`. Does the value `announcement.id` assured to be unique for each element in the `announcements` array? Is there a possibility that it is null / undefined for more than one elements?

Comment: These values are unique and there are no empty values in the database.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Please format code reasonably. Please act on my earlier comment: [mre] [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [ask] [Help] [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

You are likely passing some `undefined` or `null` value to the key prop. Check whether every announcement object has an **string** `id` property.

However, it's not recommended to use the array index as unique key when the array comes from a database (or will change at some point).